# Look through DF, find rows that contain opposite matches of two column strings

Tags: r, dataframe, string-matching

Working with a large data set of college basketball final scores, I'm looking only for cases where the two teams have played each other twice.

```
df <- data.frame(Home = c("Air Force", "Air Force", "Air Force", "BYU"), 
             HomeScore = c(79, 72, 88, 82), 
             Away = c("BYU", "Utah", "Wyoming", "Air Force"),
             AwayScore = c(83, 74, 92, 72),
             HomeMargin = c(-4, -2, -4, 10),
             HomeWin = c(0, 0, 0, 1))
```

The data was all imported from a separate database. My ultimate goal is to create a final column, "iteration" that denotes whether the home team won the same game on the road, only for matches that have happened twice (once home and once on the road).

Using the above example, Air Force played BYU once at home and once on the road. They lost the home matchup but won the road game. Row 1 would contain a "1" under "iteration", rows 2 and 3 would contain "NA", and row 4 would contain "0".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go!

```
df3 <- left_join(df, 
                 select(df, Home, Away, iteration = HomeWin), 
                     by = c("Home" = "Away", "Away" = "Home")
                 )
```

You can left join it against itself, matching on Home and Away, Away and Home, and then only bring in HomeWin.

I added the `select(df, Home, Away, iteration = HomeWin)` because I wanted to filter down that df. You could save it as something else and then reference it in the join if you'd like.

Hope this helps!

Comment: note that this will get messed up if there are situations where there is more than 2 games against each other, 1 on both sides. If BYU played Air Force twice at Home, and once away, it would screw this up, you'd need a different solution, so lmk if this works.

Comment: Thanks! With a little tweaking this was able to do the trick. Regarding your concern, I am a little alarmed that this limited my data frame to an odd number of observations. Doesn't seem like that would make sense but not going to go through all 2065 looking for the odd game.

Comment: what tweak did you make out of curiosity?